# Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ‘XXX.app/PlugIns/YYY.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. Xcode8 アプリをAppStoreにアップロードする際にエラーが起こる

Tags: swift, realm, swift3

Realmを使うためにPodfileにuse_frameworks!とpod 'RealmSwift'
を追加したのですが、そのことが原因でエクステンションアプリのパッケージ内に
Frameworksフォルダができるようになりました。

そのためAppStoreにアップロードする際に下記のようなエラーが起きます。

エラー内容

```
ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ‘XXX.app/PlugIns/YYY.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
```

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'NCMB', :git => 'https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/ncmb_ios.git'
pod 'RealmSwift'

target :”YYY”, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

エクステンションアプリ内のFrameworksフォルダ
[image: エクステンションアプリ内のFrameworksフォルダ]
試したこと1
Embed Pod Frameworksを削除しましたが解決しませんでした。

試したこと2
Run ScriptでFrameworksを削除するようにしても解決できませんでした。

試したこと3
パッケージの中から手動で削除すると審査にあげられるようになったのですが、
エクステンションアプリが起動しなくなりました。

解決方法をご存知の方、回答いただけると助かります。

Comment: CocoaPodsのバージョンはいくつですか？

Comment: Podfileの書き方から、おそらく0.39だと思うのですが、それだとSwift 3でビルドするにはこれだと足りないと思うんですよね。他にビルドするために自分でプロジェクト設定を変えたところとかありませんか？

Comment: あと、エクステンションの種類は何ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
自己解決しました。
Swift3でビルドできています。

Qiitaにメモとして残しました。
http://qiita.com/hideyukitone/items/df586c09010fd3aa3c58

Comment: エクステンションはアクションです。